# how to build an uefi application using c++

Tags: c++, build, qemu, osdev, uefi

i tried compiling

```
#include <efi.h>
#include <efilib.h>
#include <efiprot.h>

EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI
efi_main (EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *SystemTable)
{
InitializeLib(ImageHandle, SystemTable);
Print(L"XENON OS VER 0.02");
for(;;) __asm__("hlt");
}
```

using

```
gcc -Ignu-efi-dir/inc -fpic -ffreestanding -fno-stack-protector -fno-stack-check -fshort-wchar -mno-red-zone -maccumulate-outgoing-args main.cpp -o main.o
```

how ever after liking and testing it using Qemu it just got stuck at booting prossess

> if you cannot find the bug please make a simple poc C++ code i checked searched every tutorial that i could find on the web but no luck

Comment: You don't say how you're running it (QEMU command line, etc), or what output was produced.

Comment: Your suppose to convert the ELF file into the PE format using objcopy, and then format a disk image in FAT32 and place your BOOTX64.EFI file in /EFI/BOOT. Read https://wiki.osdev.org/UEFI#Developing_with_GNU-EFI